# Define Tab and Enter in VS C# to work like in Python 3.7.x

Tags: c#, wpf

For my project I'm trying to 'make' a python in VS.
I`ve made regex to highlight the syntax and now I need to make Tab, Enter and Shift+Tab to work like in python.

I doing it as a test in WPF with textbox with example text in it. I`ve made working enter as a new line and tab to be working.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox.AcceptsTab = true;
    }
    private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Tab && e.Key == Key.LeftShift)
        {
        }
    }
```

Now im trying to make:

1.Shift + Tab to remove tab.

2.When i mark a few lines and press Tab/Shift+Tab it will work for them all

3.When i press enter it aligns lines with the line before. For example:

If a line before have one tab, when I press the enter new line will also have one tab.

I`ll be glad for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it looks like your `textbox` is named `textBox` so I will use that, and begin with the code you posted.

the following seems to answer your questions, but it is ofrf the top of my head so go over it well before you use it.  I hope it helps you get started.

EDIT:  I just noticed the portion of your question dealing with highlighting multiple rows.  That is not in the code I wrote below but it can be accomplished by using `.SelectionStart` and `.SelectionLength`, determining which lines are affected, and then determining if those lines have tabs etc...

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox.AcceptsTab = true;
}
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // append newline AND maybe some tabs
        textBox.AppendText(DoEnterPressed());
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Tab && e.Key == Key.LeftShift)
    {
        // check, see and do
        DoShiftTab();
    }
}

//now we need those methods of course
private string DoEnterPressed()
{
    string ret = Environment.NewLine;
    //check how many tabs the line has...

    //I want the line we are on, not maybe the last line    
    string currentLine = textBox.GetLineText(textBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(textBox.SelectionStart) );
    //  Only counting the tab chars at the start of string makes it easier
    int tabCnt = 0;
    foreach(char c in currentLine)
    {
        if(c == '\t')
        {
            tabCnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    // now put the tabs in the return string after the newline
    for(int i = 0; i < tabCnt; i++)
    {
        ret += "\t";
    }
    return ret;
}

private void DoShiftTab()
{
    //  let's see if the char before the cursor is tab, if so, remove it
    if(textBox.text[textBox.SelectionStart-1] == '\t')
    {
        textBox.text.RemoveAt(textBox.SelectionStart-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, ill try to finish it and paste the result.